# Unable to export Access database table to SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, import, microsoft-access

I've an old Access database that I would migrate to SharePoint Online list.

I've tried to use the export tool that is available in Microsoft Access, but I receive this error:

```
There was an error copying data to a SharePoint list. The Microsoft Access database engine encountered an error while communicating with SharePoint. More detailed information:
```

My Access version is: 16.0.4266.1001 (Access 2016), but I also tried with an Access installed from the Office365 package.

My SharePoint destination site is: https://mytenant.sharepoint.com/protocols

I've also found this Microsoft KB that should refer to the same error I am encountering: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/errors-publishing-exporting

So, I've searched through attachment file names and I found some file names with two periods (..) in front of the extension. I've changed the attachment or also deleted the entire row in my tries, but I receive every time the same error.

I think the problem is with the content of some specific rows because selecting another set of rows with attachments I was able to import them on SharePoint using the same procedure.

Is there a way to check row contents before trying the export/import? Or is there a way to "clean" attachments file name with problems? I've about 4000 rows to import with attachments and I have to use an automated way to this preliminary checks.

Answer (score 0):

I’m afraid there is no automatic method to check the filenames in Microsoft Access.

As a workaround, you can export the database to Excel without selecting "Export data with formatting and layout."

The filenames of the attachments will be exported as plain texts, so that it would be a little more convenient to check for invalid characters.

[image]